# Posting Arabic Characters in Twitter using Twitter API in C# using OAuth

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, arabic

I am trying to post arabic characters to twitter using twitter api, but it does not work in default format,
String arabicenglish = "عربي/عربىHello";

```
I used string tweet = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(arabenglish);
```

But this does not work,
then i used a library which converts this into

> &# 1593;&# 1585;&# 1576;&# 1610;/&# 1593;&# 1585;&# 1576;&# 1609;Hello

This works fine, but if message gets long, it overlimits the twitter 140 limit.

So let me know whats the best way to send arabic, and count 1 arabic char = 1 english char, and workable too on twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the right link but the guy is talking about the same thing you've asked. Check it [here](http://www.lebgeeks.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=6316). Here is another [link](http://www.startuparabia.com/2008/10/artwittercom-an-arabic-interface-for-twitter/) that might interest you.